# Convert multiple poses to Collada

Tags: export, bones, pose-mode, collada

I'm new to both Blender and Collada files. How can I export multiple poses to Collada? I can add new poses in the Pose Library in Blender, but when I export the scene to Collada, only one pose seems to show up in the Collada XML.

How does Collada even express multiple poses? As far as I understand it, a `<controller>` refers to the part of the mesh being animated (e.g. face, torso), its `<skin>` defines the id of the actual mesh, the joint `<source>` defines the bones, the transform `<source>` defines the transform to be applied, the weights `<source>` defines the weight with which the transform is applied to a given vertex. Multiple poses would involve multiple transforms, but the  apparently can only refer to a single INV_BIND_MATRIX.

So, does Collada not support multiple poses? Or does Blender not support exporting them? Is there a common workaround?

Comment: A pose is just a one-frame animation. AFAIK Blender can only export (and import) one animation. Btw I recommend you avoid Collada if at all possible. It is not in a good state.